# .noscroll { overflow: hidden; position: relative; } が適用されず、スクロールできてしまう

Tags: html, css

以下のコードが機能しません。自分のパソコン以外だとうまくいくのかもしれません。

```
body.noscroll {
    overflow: hidden;
```

---

#### 実際の表示例

**スクロール前の画像**
[image: スクロール前の画像]

**スクロール後の画像**
[image: スクロール後の画像]

#### 現状のソースコード

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".question-outer dt").on("click",function(){
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
            $(this).toggleClass("open");
        })
    })
//sticky header
  $('.header-burger-btn').on('click',function(){
          $('.header-nav').fadeToggle(300);
          $('.header-burger-btn').toggleClass('cross');
          $('body').toggleClass('noscroll');
        });; 
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

  .header{
    width: 1000px;
  }
  .header-wrapper-second .header-outer {
    display: none;
  }

  .header-wrapper-second .header-outer-second {
    display: none;
  }
  .header-burger-btn .bars {
    height: 6px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: #1B224C;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 50px;
  }



  .header-burger-btn .bar_top {
    margin-top: -15px;
  }
  .header-burger-btn .bar_bottom {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }

.cross .bar_top{
    transform: rotate(40deg) translate(6px, 14px);
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 3;
  }

.cross .bar_mid {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

 .cross .bar_bottom {
    transform: rotate(-40deg) translate(6px, -14px);
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 3;
  }

  section.list-wrapper {
    height: 700px;
    padding: 120px;
  }

  .title-contact-wrapper {
    padding-right: 27px;
  }




  .header-nav {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #282F35;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  header .header-container .header-nav-color{
    padding-right: 0px;
    color: #fff;
  }


  .header-nav .header-nav-list {
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 120px 0 0;
  }


body.noscroll {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
  .header-nav .header-nav-list .header-nav-item {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .header-nav .header-nav-list .header-nav-item .header-nav-item:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
/*
template Name:トップページ
*/
?>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="共通キーワード" />
  <meta name="description" content="共通ディスクリプション" />


  <title>Engress</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/css/styles.css" />
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body class="body">
    <div class="noscroll">
<header class="header"> 
    <div class="header-container">   
    <div class="header-wrapper">      
    <div class="header-logo">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/logo1.png"/>
    </div>
    <nav class="header-nav">
        <ul class="header-nav-list">
            <li class="header-nav-item"><a class="header-nav-item-second">ホーム</a></li>
            <li class="header-nav-item"><a class="header-nav-item-third">お知らせ</a></li>
            <li class="header-nav-item"><a class="header-nav-item-fourth">ブログ</a></li>
            <li class="header-nav-item"><a class="header-nav-item-fifth">コース・料金</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>    
    <div class="header-wrapper-second">
        <div class="header-outer">
         <p class="header-time">平日08:00〜20:00</p>
         <div class="header-content">
       <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/pus 29.png" class="main-logo" alt="Engress"/>
            <div class="telephone-number">0123-456-7890</div>
        </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="header-outer-second">
            <div class="header-content-second">
                <div class="header-btn-outer">
                <a href="#" class="header-btn"  style="text-decoration: none;"><p class="header-btn-name">資料請求</p></a>
                </div>
                <div class="header-btn-outer-second">
                <a href="#" class="header-btn-second"  style="text-decoration: none;"><p class="header-btn-name">お問い合わせ</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="header-burger-btn">
        <div class="bars  bar_top"></div>
        <div class="bars bar_mid"></div>
        <div class="bars bar_bottom"></div>
    </div>
     </div>
     </div>

</header>
```

Comment: 質問文のコードの動作を、Windows 10 上の Firefox と Google Chrome を使用し確認したところ、問題が再現しないようです：https://jsfiddle.net/fdah90sy/show

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます、ただ、自分のPCでは固定されません、なぜだか、わかる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。質問者さんがこのコードを実行している環境を教えていただけませんか？また、上記のjsfiddleでも同様にスクロールされてしまうでしょうか？

Comment: VirtualBoxと、Vagrantで、KUSANAGIを使用しています。jsfiddleではスクロールされないようです。

Comment: ここでいう環境とはクライアント側の情報をさします（ブラウザやOS情報）。現象が起こるのはクライアントサイドであるならばPHPは一旦省いてHTML+CSS+JSでまずは静的なサイトを作ってみて現象が再現するか確認してみてはいかがでしょう？

Comment: お返事いただきありがとうございます。クライアントではなく、自分のローカルサーバーです。自分は、クロームでマックを使用しています。

Comment: 話が残念ながら通じていないようですここで言うクライアントとはwebサーバとクライアントのことを指します。顧客のことは指していません。

Comment: ローカルで行っていますが、ローカルでもウェブサーバーはあるのでしょうか？

Comment: あります。Vagrantを利用しているということはローカルのPC内に仮想のサーバを立てていて、そこのWebサーバを構築してアクセスしています。ローカル"サーバー"といっている以上はサーバ⇔クライアントの構成になります。

Comment: お答えいただきありがとうございました、申し訳ございませんが、https://sitereport.netcraft.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpacificmall.local%2Fなどのサイトで調べてますが、どうも、調べられませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

再現できなかったのですが、html, body, noscrollそれぞれに対して、height:100%を付与して高さを定義してあげるとうまく動くかもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。、試しましたができませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed;` の記述で、ボタン部分を固定することにしました。
未だにスクロール自体を止めることは出来ませんが。

```css
 .cross .bar_top {
    transform: rotate(40deg) translate(6px, 8px);
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 3;
    position: fixed; 
    
  }

.cross .bar_mid {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
    z-index: 3;
  }
.cross .bar_bottom {
    transform: rotate(-40deg) translate(6px, -8px);
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 3;
    position: fixed; 
  }
```